# Ruby gem for Growl

Tags: ruby, rubygems, growl

I'm looking for a gem that's able to send Growl notifications and receive a click-event on the notification. There are some gems available but the problem is none of them seem to be compatible with Ruby 1.9. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby support for Growl was released in 2004 under the BSD license. Get in touch with the developer [here](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/ruby-support.php) to see how to get access to the source code. While it might seem like a huge task to fix a lib that you can't understand, the changes from 1.8 to 1.9 that break it might be obvious if you look at the source.

[RVM](http://www.rubyinside.com/rvm-ruby-version-manager-2347.html) would be an essential tool for testing language differences between 1.8 and 1.9.x. Or it might solve your problem by allowing you to specify a Ruby version while you wait for Ruby Growl to be updated... but I wouldn't hold my breath: it hasn't been touched in years.